# Share point 2013 - 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR

Tags: 2013

I am new to share point 2013. I have create a Web Application and Site Collection in SharePoint 2013. But when I try to browse the url I am getting the below error.

Error: 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR

Please can any one help me.

Comment: Please check your ULS logs for more information and suggest you to share the event logs in the question.

Comment: I don't know how to check uls logs. Please can you tell me how to check uls logs. Please help me.

Comment: Check this blogpost of mine on how to use ULS Viewer, http://sharepointbulletin.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/how-to-use-uls-viewer-in-sharepoint.html

Comment: Please, check this helpful guide **[SharePoint: 500 Internal Server Error](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/500-internal-server-error-in-sharepoint-2013/)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1, goto central admin and see if you can get in?

2, goto iismanager and check you application pools are all running? if not start them! rightclick each one and click start! to see if they are running click on application pool folder and you should see the list on the righ side under state should be "running" or "stoped"

[image: application pool]

3, goto your site and see if its working now!

4, if not go back to iis and check to see what application pool is sturned off again!
make sure SecurityTokenServiceApplicationPool is running! if not follow this:

SecurityTokenServiceApplicationPool application pool-> Advanced Settings.

[image]

Navigated to the Identity option.

[image]

Updated the user’s credentials and clicked on OK.

do an iisreset:

[image]

goto the site and see if its working, these steps can be repeated for any app pool that keeps going off :)

[source](http://blog.cloudshare.com/2013/01/12/how-to-resolve-http-500-internal-server-error-in-sharepoint-2013-site/)

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. I have tried all above options but still getting 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR. Please help me.

Comment: did you see any that were no running?

Comment: all are running.

Comment: I have reset the iis and the error is resolved.

Comment: glad to see your problem is resolved! as I always say "if in dout iisreset" lol, seems to solve alot of issues