# Site Collection '500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR'

Tags: 2013, site, collection

Opening a newly created site collection on SharePoint 2013 throws '500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR'

Comment: Please, check this guide for addiotnal root causes **[SharePoint: 500 Internal Server Error](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/500-internal-server-error-in-sharepoint-2013/)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Resolving 500 Internal Server Error** [ [Source](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/62993/9345) ]

1. Go to **Central Administration** and see if you access.
2. Go to **IIS Manager** and check you application pools are all running. If not, start your application pools. To see if they are running click on Application Pool folder and you should see the list on the right-side under state should be "running" or "stopped".

[image]

3. Go to your **site** and see if its working now.
4. If not, go back to IIS and check to see what application pool is turned off again. Make sure **SecurityTokenServiceApplicationPool** is running. If not follow this:

   - SecurityTokenServiceApplicationPool Application Pool -> Advanced Settings.

[image]

- Navigated to the Identity option.

[image]

- Updated the User’s Credentials and clicked on OK.

[image]

5. Do an **IIS Reset**.
6. Go to the **site** and see if its working, these steps can be repeated for any app pool that keeps going off.

[ [Source](http://blog.cloudshare.com/2013/01/12/how-to-resolve-http-500-internal-server-error-in-sharepoint-2013-site/) ]

Answer (score 1):

In my case when i went to View Site Collection in CA the details were blank so i knew it was the database.

Luckily we use a standard naming convention so i knew the DBs name.

Went to the SQL server and checked the SQL logs, the DB had recovered from a corruption but when i compared the Site Collection db's permissions to another working one the permissions for two values were missing:

select permission for spdataaccess and spreadonly

Added the values back and the site came up.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this error for SharePoint , you can also check about the IIS feature delegation to the Central Admin.

In the site hosting server,--> start-->run-->inetmgr-->click on server-->features view--> Management pane-->double click on Feature Delegation-->Handler mapping--> change it to Read/Write.