# 500 Internal Server Error Site Collection

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I am new to SharePoint and learning at the moment.

When I try to create a site collection I am facing issue of 500 Server not found.

I have checked following articles

- [Site Collection '500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR'](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/138430/site-collection-500-internal-server-error)
- [How to resolve http 500 internal server error in-sharepoint 2013 site](http://blog.cloudshare.com/blog/how-to-resolve-http-500-internal-server-error-in-sharepoint-2013-site)

But these didn't help.

Following is the screenshot:

https://s31.postimg.org/493tci9i3/Screenshot_15.png

I can't see anything weird in this.

Please suggest me.

Comment: @Dikesh Gandhi : Can you please help me with this.

Comment: Should you try to upload screenshot again , it's not shown !

Comment: @M.Qassas http://imgur.com/ website is down. So Stack API is not able to upload images. I have shared a direct URL to another image hosting website

https://s31.postimg.org/493tci9i3/Screenshot_15.png

Comment: when you try adding /_layouts/15/settings.aspx  after /sites/training can you open the site collections setting page?

Comment: @ova : I tried as per your comment 
http://hostname/sites/training/_layouts/15/settings.aspx

It also takes me to 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: Is this occur for all sites or only this new site ? also How many WFE within your farm ?

Comment: @M.Qassas This occurs for all sites. Sorry I don't understand the term WFE. 

I have only single web application in Web Farm.
I  am a newbie and taking guide from Pluralsight Course

Comment: What is sharepoint version and what OS you are using for it?

Comment: I am using Sharepoint Server 2013 Trail and have installed it on Windows 10 Home(Reference taken from article - [Install Sharepoint on WIndows](http://www.disruptivei.com/Blogg/Inl%C3%A4gg/6/Install-SharePoint-2013-on-Windows-7-8-8-1))

Answer (score 2):

**First of all,** the **[500 internal server error](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/500-internal-server-error-in-sharepoint-2013/)** is a general HTTP status that refers to a strange issue happened on the IIS server and the server can't identify it.

**Therefore,** the root cause for this issue mainly differs from one environment to another, and actually, there is no direct solution.

So, at first glance, you should check what's the last action you have done on your environment and start from that point.

---

**In general,** the 500 internal server error usually occurs if

- [Web config file was modified in an incorrect format.](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/500-internal-server-error-in-sharepoint-2013/#Web-config-file-wasnbspmodifiednbspinnbspincorrect-format)
- [Application Pool stopped or not started.](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/500-internal-server-error-in-sharepoint-2013/#Application-Pool-stopped-or-not-started)
- [Application Pool Account Password has expired.](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/500-internal-server-error-in-sharepoint-2013/#Application-Pool-Started-then-Stopped-Again)
- [Security Token Service Application Pool stopped.](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/500-internal-server-error-in-sharepoint-2013/#Security-Token-Service-Application-Pool-stopped)
- [Application Pool Account doesn't have sufficient rights.](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/500-internal-server-error-in-sharepoint-2013/#Grant-8220Impersonate-a-client-after-authentication8221-right-for-Application-Pool-Account)

> For more details, Please check **[SharePoint: 500 Internal Server Error](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/500-internal-server-error-in-sharepoint-2013/)**

Comment: I am using Windows 10 Home for Sharepoint Server using www.disruptivei.com/Blogg/Inlägg/6/Install-SharePoint-2013-on-Windows-7-8-8-1 and there are not Local Security Policy available in Home Edition.