# http://500 server internal error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

Sudenly i get this error:

I tried those solution and non of them works

1. Site Collection '500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR' so i follrw the step here : 
   [enter link description here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/138430/site-collection-500-internal-server-error)
2. clear the cache of sharepoint
3. in event viewer i got this error detail :

> 'contractType:Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustServiceContract;name:SecurityTokenService'

Update:
here is the log files :

[Any idea please ?](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B6yaDRhbKDUzUmtxcEd5WGxwZE0?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hi Imen, Could you please check this **[SharePoint: 500 Internal Server Error](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/500-internal-server-error-in-sharepoint-2013/)**

Comment: Hi M.Qassas , it's not related to one webapplication. all webapplications. IF I create a new webapplication. i got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Open event viewer and there go to **Windows logs -> Application** and check that you don't have any password expiration message or any service login failure related issues.If any issues related to login failure then you have to update the password of that account everywhere it is been used.in Application pool as well as in services

and if this not work try the following links it may help you:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/79103340-6381-4f99-a49e-2abc0c45f4a1/internal-server-error-500-security-token-service-problem?forum=sharepointadmin
[500 Internal Server Error Site Collection](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/187825/500-internal-server-error-site-collection?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Let me know if you face any issues.

**UPDATE**

Follow this link it has same issue which you are facing:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4712c8fd-10f0-4c51-86cb-a7272f8cca3f/claims-authentication-error-event-id-8305?forum=sharepointadmin

Comment: 8305:'contractType:Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustServiceContract;name:SecurityTokenService'

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons for 500 error. Basically this error indicates that issue is on the server. i would do the following to troubleshoot the issue.

- enable the Http trace log and get the in depth details of error. [Follow this link to enable it](http://krossfarm.com/?p=167)
- Check the web.config file if there is any typo or something wrong
- Check the IIS and make sure all sites are up and running.
- reset IIS
- try to browse the Security token service page and see if it is displaying proper xml...check this link https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sambetts/2014/03/17/sharepoint-health-report-error-the-security-token-service-is-not-available/
- check the event log ( application, system, setup) and share the detailed error.
- check if any firewall blocking the ports or any Antivirus blocking it?

Comment: Thank you Waqas, i tried all with no points , i even create a new webapplication and i got the same error. I could not found a reason for that !!

Comment: did you enable the http trace any error reported over there? any error in event log(share the complete error)? are you accessing sites from server or client machine? is the root level site collections in place?

Comment: here is the log files : https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B6yaDRhbKDUzUmtxcEd5WGxwZE0?usp=sharing

Comment: couple of things to check...is DC is up and running, Security Token service is working and UPA is also configured properly

Comment: Thanl you for your answer , would you please explained more , i didn't get it

Comment: What i am seeing in the trace log, it is failing around the authentication....so that's mean either Security Token service is not working properly?https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sykhad-msft/2012/02/24/sharepoint-2010-nailing-the-error-the-security-token-service-is-unavailable/

Comment: Also check if the distributed cache is up and running

Comment: also check the creditnal of the account using the app pool is correct. check this blog https://sysadminspot.com/server-administration/isapi-filter-cwindowsmicrosoft-netframeworkv4-0-30319aspnet_filter-dll-could-not-be-loaded-due-to-a-configuration-problem/  and  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/76e66c62-d41e-4c90-8efc-3746c9a40dad/internal-server-error-500

Comment: did not found a solution , i think i will reinstall Sharepoint

Comment: I am sorry I can't do sharing as I am in office...but I think issue with iis rather Sharepoint