# (SOLVED) Newly Created Site Collection Throws 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: error, site-collection, configuration, internal-server-error

I've been getting an 500 error everytime I tried to access the site. I've tried the solution posted in [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/62973/share-point-2013-500-internal-server-error/) but the SecurityTokenServiceApplicationPool is running normally. I also checked the event viewer and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfFZL.jpg) is the error. Is there any way to fix this? I've tried creating another Site Collection and Web Application but still have the same results. Thanks

EDIT: I've fixed the problem by restarting the SharePoint Web Services Site in IIS. Thank you.

Comment: Can you check a couple of things? Is Named Pipes under SQL Server Network Configuration enabled? If not, enable it. Also grant the 'View Server State' permission to the account that the error is complaining about using the following commands: 
USE master 
GO 
GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE TO "Domain\Account"
GO

Comment: @AndyDawson Hello, I've tried doing what you've suggested and still encountered same problem. After reading the ULS logs I've pinpointed that the problem stems from a broken Security Token Service configuration. I've tried using fixes from [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sambetts/2014/03/17/sharepoint-health-report-error-the-security-token-service-is-not-available/) and [here](http://asharepointsolutions.blogspot.co.id/2015/01/troubleshooting-sharepoint-http-500.html) but the site still gives me 500 internal server error. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issue and it was recurring so you might hit this issue again, In my case this is happens due to the fact that STS identity is unloaded. By changing in STS Application Pool 'Load User Profile' property to true we managed to resolve it permanently.

Another way of resolving it was to [change GPO](http://Computer%20Configuration-%3EAdministrative%20Templates-%3ESystem-%3E%20UserProfiles%20%20Do%20not%20forcefully%20unload%20the%20user%20registry%20at%20user%20logoff):
Computer Configuration->Administrative Templates->System-> UserProfiles 
Do not forcefully unload the user registry at user logoff