# how to debug SharePoint 2013 500 Internal Server error

Tags: 2013, 2010, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, internal-server-error

Currently getting 500 internal error on Sharepoint 2013 server.

I'm currently in the process of upgrading a SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013.

I've been unable to hit the homepage yet. The most recent error I've gotten is this 500 internal server error. I'm having issue tracing the source of the issue and would like some guidance with resolving the issue.  I've already check 
[Share point 2013 - 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/62973/share-point-2013-500-) internal-server-error. But its solution wasn't helpful.

---

### UPDATE

[image]

Comment: are you browsing the site from Server or client pc

Comment: I've done both on the server itself and another pc on the network.

Comment: Have you checked your site bindings in IIS? Also, do you have a valid SSL certificate?

Answer (score 1):

their are couple of things to check, some time error is misleading.

- Try different browser ( IE, EDGE or Chrome) and see if you get different error code.
- Make sure loopback check disable on the Server.
- Make sure database connectivity has no issue
- DNS is proper configured / AAM settings are correct.
- Make Sure App Pool is up and running (Form IIS)
- Web Site is also started ( from IIS)
- Check event log, if there is any error related to it.
- can you browse the Central admin site?
- Make sure their is no blockage on the server i.e. firewall, antivirus etc
- You can also configured the Failed Request trace IIS to get more detail about the error.

[check this blog:](https://sharepointsupportiis.blogspot.com/2015/03/troubleshooting-sharepoint-http-500.html)

Comment: Thanks!, I will start working through those suggestions,   Also Central Admin is up and all App Pools are started and running.